# Google Analytics Module: Sub Domains

Tags: google-analytics

I am using a Drupal Multiple Site (several sites running on 1 Drupal installation). Each site is part of a subdomain.

For example:

- mysite.com
- store.mysite.com
- blog.mysite.com

Each site has its own separate database. Do I set up Google Analytics on just the main site or on all the sites?

[In this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1255792), it says you need to set it up on all the sites. However, it also says you need to  "show the ".domain setting" in footer". I can't find this setting anywhere in the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to install the module on each site using the same UA# (assuming these should all be tracked under the same account).

All you need to do is select `One domain with multiple subdomains` for everything to track properly.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer of the question depending on how you want to track each website in GA.

First off, since you have multiple configurations/databases, you'll need to setup GA (@ **/admin/config/system/googleanalytics**) on each the site if you're wanting to track each one, regardless how you track the sites in GA.

Next, if you're wanting to track **each site separately in a different GA property** (each with its own independent tracking metrics/dimensions/etc), you want to use the `A single domain (default)` option with each site having a different `Web Property ID` (e.g. UA-xxxxxxx-yy).

If you're wanting to track all these interrelated  ***sites on one GA property***, you'll need to use the `One domain with multiple subdomains` option. You'll be using the `Web Property ID` across all sites, but you'll have to make additional configurations to accommodate GA:

- If you're not using Universal Analytics, this means that the 
  `$cookie_domain` (in **settings.php**) needs to tweaked so that it reports to GA the same .mysite.com domain (this is what your linked d.o. is addressing).
- If you are using Universal Analytics, then just setting the `One domain with multiple subdomains` option is fine.

Note, if you go with the `One domain with multiple subdomains` option, you'll need to make some additional changes on the GA side so that [filters show the domain](http://www.wearefine.com/mingle/filtering-subdomains-in-google-analytics/). Otherwise, you're going to see various domain URLs mixed into the GA property.